# Measure Vcc using 1.1V bandgap

Tags: c++, voltage-level, adc

For an battery driven application I want to measure the Vcc (using an Atmega 32u4). That is my code:

```
int readBandGap() {
  ADMUX = (B01 << REFS0)    // VCC
        | (0 << ADLAR)      // right-adjusted result
        | (B011110 << MUX0) // 1.1V
        ;
  // switch off any ADC conversion
  ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN);
  // enable ADC
  ADCSRA |= 1 << ADEN;
  // start ADC
  ADCSRA |= 1 << ADSC;
  // wait until finished
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADSC));
  // first read low, then high!
  uint8_t low = ADCL;
  uint8_t high = ADCH;
  // switch off any ADC conversion
  ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN);
  return (high << 8) | low;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int value = readBandGap();
  float vcc = 1.1 * 1023 / value;
  Serial.print(value);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.println(vcc);

  delay(1000);
}
```

My Olimexino 32u4 board has the ability to switch the voltage between 5V and 3.3V. There are two strange things:

1. the first measurement is always significantly different than the later measurements
2. with 5V I'm getting 450, followed by ~367; with 3.3V I'm getting 422, followed by ~395. I would have expected a higher Vcc resulting in a lower measured value (bandgap should be measured compared to Vcc).

Any ideas what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: I have known good Vcc measuring code here: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/making-accurate-adc-readings-on-arduino - You might like to compare it with your code - especially the bit that delays to allow Vref to settle.

Comment: I've tried that code now and `readVcc` always reports ~1100, no matter whether I'm using 3.3 or 5V. Maybe for the 32u4 some different flags have to be used.

Comment: Given that code was written for the 328P with fewer ADC inputs, yes, you probably need to adjust the MUX settings to get the right channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking a lot, I've now have found following code to work quite good.

```
float readVcc() {
  ADMUX = (B01 << REFS0)    // VCC
        | (0 << ADLAR)      // right-adjusted result
        | (B011110 << MUX0) // 1.1V
        ;
  // enable ADC
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);
  // seems necessary
  delay(2);
  // start ADC
  ADCSRA |= 1 << ADSC;
  // wait until finished
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADSC));
  // first read low, then high!
  long value = ADCL;
  value |= ADCH << 8;
  return 1.1 / value * 1023;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bandgap voltage reference needs some time to stabilize, after you enable it. See http://jeelabs.org/2012/05/12/improved-vcc-measurement/

Doing 3 dummy measurements, gives it enough time to do that.