# Measure different Vcc using 1.1V bandgap

Tags: atmega328, voltage-level, adc

When I power my ATmega328P chip from 5.16V and 3.3V, there doesn't seem to be a single bandgap voltage compensation figure that works for both.

I'm using the following sketch, and I need the following `InternalReferenceVoltage` values to read the correct voltage from `A0`:

- `1255L` to correctly output 5.16V.
- `1358L` to correctly output 3.3V.

I have a couple of questions:

- Should I be able to use a single `InternalReferenceVoltage` compensation value whe powering the ATmega328P from different voltages?
- Aren't both of these values outside the specced 1.0 to 1.2 range?

The code is from, http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=56750.msg407897#msg407897, retolefty post @ Mar 28, 2011, 02:27 pm.

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup()
{
  delay(5000);

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(void)
{
  // Determines what actual Vcc is, (X 100), based on known bandgap voltage
  int battVolts = readVcc1();

  Serial.print("Battery Vcc volts =  ");
  Serial.println(battVolts);
  Serial.print("Analog pin 0 voltage = ");
  Serial.println(map(analogRead(0), 0, 1023, 0, battVolts));
  Serial.println();

  delay(1000);
}

// Returns actual value of Vcc (x 100)
int readVcc1()
{
  uint8_t oldADMUX = ADMUX;

  const long InternalReferenceVoltage = 1255L; // Adjust this value to your boards specific internal BG voltage x1000

#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  // For mega boards
  // REFS1 REFS0          --> 0 1, AVcc internal ref. -Selects AVcc reference
  // MUX4 MUX3 MUX2 MUX1 MUX0  --> 11110 1.1V (VBG)         -Selects channel 30, bandgap voltage, to measure
  ADMUX = (0 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0) | (0 << ADLAR) | (0 << MUX5) | (1 << MUX4) | (1 << MUX3) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX1) | (0 << MUX0);

#else
  // For 168/328 boards
  // REFS1 REFS0          --> 0 1, AVcc internal ref. -Selects AVcc external reference
  // MUX3 MUX2 MUX1 MUX0  --> 1110 1.1V (VBG)         -Selects channel 14, bandgap voltage, to measure
  ADMUX = (0 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0) | (0 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX3) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX1) | (0 << MUX0);

#endif
  delay(50); // Let mux settle a little to get a more stable A/D conversion
  // Start a conversion
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC);
  // Wait for it to complete
  while (((ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)) != 0));

  // Scale the value
  int results = (((InternalReferenceVoltage * 1023L) / ADC) + 5L) / 10L; // calculates for straight line value

  ADMUX = oldADMUX;

  return results;
}
```

I have read these other references to try and find a solution:

- [Measure Vcc using 1.1V bandgap](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16352/measure-vcc-using-1-1v-bandgap)
- https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/making-accurate-adc-readings-on-the-arduino/
- http://provideyourown.com/2012/secret-arduino-voltmeter-measure-battery-voltage/

Comment: I don't get the question. The idea is not to measure the 3.3v or 5v using the internal reference voltage as a reference, but the other way around. You measure the internal reference voltage in relation to Vcc.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I should change the code or the measurements then? I thought measuring Vcc using the internal reference would allow me to calculate how my particular internal reference varies from 1.1V.

Comment: After reading your question one more time, I finally get it. Forget what I said, as it's not related.

Answer (score 1):

The internal reference won't change much. That's why it's a reference.

Running this code on my Atmega328P:

```c++
void setup ()
{
  ADMUX = bit (REFS0) | bit (REFS1);  // Internal 1.1V reference
}
void loop () { }
```

That outputs the reference voltage on Aref. I measured it as follows with different values for Vcc:

```
Vcc     Aref
------------
5.00   1.085
4.00   1.081
3.30   1.080
3.00   1.079
```

So you can see that it retains, more or less, the same voltage regardless of Vcc. In any case, there is no way of measuring Aref, unless you have *another* reference voltage around to compare it to.

Comment: Thanks. So do I measure the voltage on the AREF pin with a multimeter to calibrate an individual chip? I'm sure I read somewhere that the internal voltage reference was never made physically available externally. I'm still not clear on how to fine tune an individual chip to get more accurate voltage readings of the battery powering the chip.

Comment: What I posted above was done by measuring with a multimeter after running that code which puts the internal voltage reference onto the Aref pin. And yes, it varies from chip to chip. As you can see, mine is slightly under 1.1V.

Comment: Thanks. I measure 1.078V on AREF (using multimeter) following your sketch, but when I use that value as the InternalReferenceVoltage value (from your "Internal Voltage Sensor" code - http://www.gammon.com.au/adc) I get 4.35V printed, when my voltage is 5.16V. I measure Vcc continuously in the loop. Confused.

Comment: What raw ADC reading do you get? Mine reads low (4.95V - raw reading: 226) but not **that** low. See [this thread on AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avrs-measure-their-own-vcc-do-it-badly) - it appears that there are some inconsistencies between theory and practice.

Comment: The difference between 4.95V and 5V (that I got) is only 1%, so that is probably acceptable for checking input voltage. Your results of 4.35V sounds like some sort of error. I tried a different approach using an external reference voltage (TL431 chip) and got better results. I can amend my answer if you want to see that. However that may have other drawbacks (depending on whether you are using the analog inputs for other purposes as well).

Comment: A bit of testing with an external reference still gives readings that fluctuate a bit. I suggest an error of a percent or two is probably normal for the ADC.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and the AVR Freaks link.  I've tried another 328P and get 1.08V for bandgap, 255 raw ADC, and the 2nd code prints 4.32V for the 5.16V source.  I can measure the battery V using 'standard' ADC relative to my boost converter's 3.3V [1], but the 'native on-chip' way seems more portable so I'd prefer to do it that way unless I've missed something.  I am new to this after all!  I *do* have an old and cheap multimeter, so I probably ought to buy a second to verify my measurements.  [1] the boost converter is not involved in my testing, my 3.3V is from a LD33V chip.